# Adding an additional method to lua's string works in official Lua but it doesn't work on Warcraft 1.12 Lua

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft, vanilla-wow-lua

In Warcraft Vanilla 1.12 Lua there's no built-in support for ("foo %s"):format("xyz") (there's only format("foo %s", "xyz")).

So I thought to add a polyfill of sorts like so:

```lua
local _format = assert(format or string.format) -- vanilla-wow-lua does have format on the global scope so we can use it here
local _getmetatable = assert(getmetatable)
local _setmetatable = assert(setmetatable)

local _stringMetatable = _getmetatable(string)
if not _stringMetatable then
    _stringMetatable = { __index = {} } -- standard-lua returns a metatable but wow-lua returns nil
    _setmetatable(string, _stringMetatable)
end

function _stringMetatable:format2(formatString, ...)
    if not unpack then
        return _format(self, formatString, ...) -- official lua
    end

    return _format(self, formatString, unpack(arg)) -- warcraft
end

_stringMetatable.__index.format2 = _stringMetatable.format2
```

This gets loaded just fine both in official lua (https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) and on the World of Warcraft 1.12. However if we try to use it like so:

```lua
local foobar = ("foo %s"):format2("abc")
print(foobar)
```

This only works on the official lua. Warcraft throws an error which says "attempt to index a string value".

If I switch over to function-call style then it works on both standard-lua and wow-lua:

```lua
local foobar = string.format2("foo %s", "abc")
print(foobar)
```

I can't understand why Warcraft fails to cooperate in this regard when it comes to strings. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What Lua version is used in WOW? `print(_VERSION)`

Comment: @ESkri it uses a trimmed down version of Lua 5.1 - certain features are missing

Comment: If you are not allowed to index a string then the critical feature is missed.

Comment: In Lua generally, you don't need to do anything complicated to get `("..."):x`; `string==getmetatable("").__index`; anything added to `string` will be accessible by indexing strings. The `string` table itself doesn't otherwise have any special meaning (ie the metatable of `string` is not the metatable of string values). Note that you can't reassign the string metatable itself without `debug.setmetatable`. Probably there is no string metatable assigned in WoW Lua (which may have been the baseline case in earlier versions of Lua, so it may be a backward compat thing).